# ruby regular expression replace repeated matches on string

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I need to parse a string in ruby which contain vars of ids and names like this `{2,Shahar}`.

The string is like this:

```
text = "Hello {1,Micheal}, my name is {2,Shahar}, nice to meet you!"
```

when I am trying to parse it, the regexp skips the first `}` and I get something like this:

```
text.gsub(/\{(.*),(.*)\}/, "\\2(\\1)")
=> "Hello Shahar(1,Micheal}, my name is {2), nice to meet you!"
```

while the required resault should be:

```
=> "Hello Michael(1), my name is Shahar(2), nice to meet you!"
```

I would be thankful to anyone who can help.

Thanks
Shahar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The greedy `.*` matches too much. It means "any string, maximum possible length". So the first `(.*)` matches `1,Micheal}, my name is {2`, then the comma matches the comma, and the second `(.*)` matches `Shahar` (and the final `\}` matches the closing braces.

Better be more specific. For example, you could restrict the match to allow only characters except braces to ensure that a match will never extend beyond the scope of a `{...}` section:

```
text.gsub(/\{([^{}]*),([^{}]*)\}/, "\\2(\\1)")
```

Or you could do this:

```
text.gsub(/\{([^,]*),([^}]*)\}/, "\\2(\\1)")
```

where the first part may be any string that doesn't contain a comma, the second part may be any string that doesn't contain a `}`.